# how to save tensorflow save model multiple files in php

Tags: javascript, php, tensorflow

I have developed a neural network model with tensorflow. I want to save weights of my model on each time they update. So i though of updating a file on the server every time it learns. but the documentation on tensorflow js website on saving model using http server is really confusing. So i did some research and found some code. Still it is not working. I know i am missing the "multipart/form-data" and fact that there are two files, "The body consist of two files, with filenames model.json and model.weights.bin". Could not find anything that could help me. [link to tensorflow documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/model-save-load.html)!

javascript to save

```
model.save('http://example.com/save.php');
```

save.php

```
<?php
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
$fname = "weights.json";

$file = fopen("../static/" .$fname, 'w');
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024)){
    fwrite($file, $data);
}

fclose($file);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for the php code you used? Are you sure it is saving over standard input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

I don't see the input section with php stdin. This makes me feel like the connection isn't sending a stream like a socket connection, but rather a standard HTTP payload with a body attribute. But wait, theirs caveats. If it is a JSON payload you'll need the second two lines (like you had in your code, but not as a resource). The first two are my guess as to what may be going on. Remember you can debug through your browsers console to see the data payload, request method, ect...

```
$data = '<pre>' . json_encode($_POST) . '</pre>';
file_put_contents('stdPost.html', $data);
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents('stdInput.json', $data);
```